# How install PDFLIB and see in phpinfo

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I'm trying to make PDFlib to work on wamp. I've downloaded http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/ and followed the installation guide ..

```
I took the libpdf_php.dll and i copied it in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext (of course i take php-540_VS9 of libpdf?  ) i have php version 5.4.12

than i added in php.ini : extension = libpdf_php.dll
```

my pc and my operating system to windows 7 x64, I can't make it work I do not get this section of pdflib in phpinfo() :

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first of all, it's not recommended to download the old and outdated PDFlib 8 for starting
- then its important, that you copy the *correct* DLL depending to your used PHP version to your extension_dir. You find the correct `extension_dir` in your phpinfo() output.
- then you have to add the PDFlib DSO to the correct `php.ini`. You find the path to the correct `php.ini` in the phpinfo() output.
- also when you are on a 64-bit Windows systems, it't important that you use a 32-bit PHP stack when using the old PHP 5.4. (PHP versions before 7.0 do support 64-bit in on Windows just in experimental use. PDFlib don't provide precomiled DSO for such combinations

In addition, I would recommend, to check the error/webserver log file, possible hints why the extension loading failed.

Comment: i used all that but not display in phpinfo() i see in wampserver php extension libpdf how can i test that is ok

Comment: I'm sure, when you carefully re-do the recommended steps, you will get it working. As a first step, you might write down, the exact steps you did. Please copy also the related values from the phpinfo() output. BTW, the [PDFlib in PHP HowTo](http://www.pdflib.com/developer/technical-documentation/howtos/) helps you also to get it working.

Comment: Firstly i have wampserver 2.4 and php 5.4.12  so i extracted the package of pdflib 8.0.6MSWIN32 and i take php-540_VS9/libpdf_php.dll  i copied it in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext ;than i added in php.ini : extension = libpdf_php.dll and restart wampserver but in phpinfo() not display section of pdflib;how can i resolved that thanks in advance

Comment: It might be helpful, when you can share the related entries from your phpinfo() output. You might find the related entries in the first block of the phpinfo() output as well the correct extension_dir path in the "Core" section. In addition, please check your **webserver/php error log** file for any messages.

Comment: thanks i change the version of wampserver and installed pdflib